# Can I combine 2 rows in R

Tags: r

A section of dataframe looks like

```r
Streets <- c("Muscow tweede","Muscow NDSM", "kazan Bo", "Kazan Ca")
Hotels<- c(5,9,4,3)
```

Is there a method to merge Muscow tweede and Muscow ndsm, as well as the two Kazan streets, so that I can find the total number of hotels in the city rather than separate streets?

Comment: `streets_to_group <- sub(' .*', '', streets)`. Then group based on your new vector

Comment: @Sotos that won't work if you have cities with more than one word in the name (obviously works with this example though)

Answer (score 0):

```
df1$City = stringr::str_to_title(stringr::word(Streets, end = 1))
aggregate(Hotels ~ City,  data = df1, sum)

    City Hotels
1  Kazan      7
2 Muscow     14
```

Sample data

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Streets = c("Muscow tweede","Muscow NDSM", "kazan Bo", "Kazan Ca"),
  Hotels = c(5,9,4,3))
```

Comment: Please include all the packages you used (`%>%`). Also since you are doing the dplyr pipe why not continue with `group_by() %>% summarise()`?

Comment: The pipe is from `magrittr`.

Comment: Sorry about that, removed pipe.

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(col=tolower(sub(' .*', '', Streets))) %>%
   summarize(Hotels=sum(Hotels))
```

Output:

```
 col    Hotels
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 kazan       7
2 muscow     14
```

Comment: You don't need `sapply` there or two `group_by`

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

tibble(Streets, Hotels) %>% 
      mutate(Streets = str_to_title(str_extract(Streets, '\\w+'))) %>% 
          group_by(Streets) %>% summarise(Hotels = sum(Hotels))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Streets Hotels
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 Kazan        7
2 Muscow      14
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way with `tapply` -

```
with(df, tapply(Hotels, tools::toTitleCase(sub('\\s.*', '', Streets)), sum))

# Kazan Muscow 
#     7     14
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rowsum` from `base R`

```
rowsum(Hotels, tools::toTitleCase(trimws(Streets, whitespace = "\\s+.*")))
       [,1]
Kazan     7
Muscow   14
```